# Mobile menu not activating on Mobile "touch"

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Having an issue with a responsive menu when on mobile.

The mobile version of the menu drops down when tapping on a computer, but when testing it on a mobile phone, the menu does not drop down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Link: http://4grain.bmdigitalgroup.com/

Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with your `gumby-trigger` not sure exactly what is causing the problem but I found a solution.

Since you are just trying to add the `active` class to the `ul` this will work

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
        $('ul.nine').toggleClass('active');
    })
});
</script>
```

**Recommendation**: I would add ID's to the button and the actual menu. That way you can call them in jQuery using ID's rather than classes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am .JS illiterate haha. Wehere exactly should I drop that couple lines of js? I am currently in the gumby.toggleswitch.js file. Thanks so much!

Comment: ok I updated the code in my answer. copy and paste that below the `<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` line in your HTML

Comment: It now works on mobile and looks awesome! Only issue is it stopped working on desktop. Thanks SO MUCH for your help on this! You are awesome!

Comment: Do you think it is a huge deal? I do not see a large % of users minimizing their screens on desktop enough to switch to a mobile menu. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Yeah it's probably not a huge deal. But try removing `gumby-trigger` on the toggle button and see if that makes it work.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Remember to check this answered as solved... if it's solved :)